# Get a google sign in button on React Native Expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I already have working google sign in, although with just a regular button. How do I render a button that matches google's sign in guidelines with the rainbow G and all? I cannot use the [React Native Google Sign In](https://github.com/react-native-google-signin/google-signin) package, as I am using Expo Go.

Comment: You must make one by yourself using `TouchableOpacity` and google sign in icon.

Answer (score -1):

how you doing ?

So, the best way to get a nice Google, Facebook login in expo is doing a good custom button, is not fair just to tell you to do your own, without even let an example for you. right ?

The best advise is to use React Native Elements, it helps a lot doing your components in React Native and its also avaible to Expo.

**#The killer social icons from react native elements would be awesome!**
https://reactnativeelements.com/docs/2.3.2/social_icon

- you can also use an fontawesome button

**An speacial snack example i made to you.**
https://snack.expo.dev/VCYpu9tk1

**oficial docs**
https://docs.expo.dev/guides/icons/#button-component

Comment: There are no icons that have the rainbow G unfortunately